# Do I need gpu while working with pretrained model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, cpu

I am already using Google Colab to train my model. So I will not use my own GPU for training. I want to ask, is there a performance difference beetween GPU and CPU while working with pre-trained model. I already trained a model with Google Colab GPU and used with my own local CPU. Should I use GPU for testing?

Comment: Mostly GPU is used for training, because training is a time consuming operation, but prediction is not. There should be no difference for your model performance training with GPU or CPU.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how many predictions you need to do. Usually in training you are making many calculations therefore parallelisation by GPU shortens overall training time. Usually, when using a trained model you just need to do a sparse prediction per time unit. In such situation CPU approach should be OK. However, if you need to do as many predictions as during training then GPU would be beneficial. This can particularly be true with reinforcement training, when your model must adopt to continuously changing environmental input.